# How to merge uneven tables in R

Tags: r

In the case that

```
a=3 and 
b= data.frame(1:2,3:4).
```

I am trying to merge `a` and b such that 3 remains in the first row, `1 3` remains in the second row and `2 4` remains in the third row.

I tried with rbind but it results in `NA`. I would like to omit NA as well.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rbind` to bind the vector with the data.frame

```
length(a) <- ncol(b)
rbind(a, b)
#   X1.2 X3.4
#1    3    NA
#2    1    3
#3    2    4
```

Comment: I just want single 3 in the first row. rbind results in 3 3 in the first row.

Comment: @user28725  You need to have a missing value `NA` to fill up the next column.  One option is pad NA at the end of 'a' and then rbind

Comment: Is there a way to remove NA and keep it empty

Comment: @user28725  I would recommend to keep it as NA instead of "", because it will change the column type to `character`

Comment: @user28725  If you are okay to have a character column, then use `rbind(replace(a, is.na(a), ""), b)`